# Understanding if a file is an image or a video from its content

Tags: php, file-upload

I can not find a way to understand if a file is really a video or an image.
For example: I have a .jpg image renamed .mp4, if I open it via computer or browser I can not see anything because it is not really a video.
What I'm looking for is a way to understand if a video / image beyond the required extension is also really a video or an image, depending on the request.
In theory I would like a similar result:

```
$ImageOrVideo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
switch($ImageOrVideo){
    case 'jpg': //check if a real image
    case 'mp4': // check if a real video
    default: exit('stop');
}
```

I had thought of some solutions, for example in the past I had used for the images getimagesize (), but now the php documentation says:

> Caution This function expects filename to be a valid image file. If a
>   non-image file is supplied, it may be incorrectly detected as an image
>   and the function will return successfully, but the array may contain
>   nonsensical values.
>
> Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image.
>   Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead.

Comment: And have you tried using the `Fileinfo` extension as the documentation suggests?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: And you're having problems with it?

Comment: Yes, he can not figure out if it's really a video.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ImageOrVideo = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
switch(mime_content_type($ImageOrVideo)){ 
        case 'image/jpeg':
             // ........
             break;
        case 'video/mp4':
             // ........
             break;
        default:
             exit('stop');
 }
```